# A question about 2 differentiable functions satisfying certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The following question was asked in my Mid Semester and I am having trouble solving it .

> Let f,g : $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ be two differentiable functions such that f(x+1,y)=f(x,y+1)=f(x,y) and g(x+1,y)=g(x,y+1)=g(x,y)for all (x,y)$\in \mathbb{R}^2$ . Choose correct statements from below :

1. f is uniformly continuous .
2. f is bounded .
3. The function (f,g):$\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is differentiable .
4. If$\partial \frac {f}{dx}=\partial \frac {g}{dy} $ and $\partial \frac {f}{dy}=-\partial \frac {g}{dx} $ , then the function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ sending (x+iy) f(x,y)+ig(x,y) (with x,y $\in \mathbb{R}$) is constant .

As [0,1] and [1,0] are periods of  both f and g and as f and g are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ so continuous on compact set $[0,1] \times [1,0]$ so , it is bounded and unformly continuous on that compact set and hence bounded and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ So, 1 ,2 are true .

I think (c) should be true as both f and g are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ but i don't know how to prove it . ( I am terrible in multivariable calculus) . Kindly tell how should I do it .

(d) The condition given in D is Cauchy Riemann equation , which tells that f  is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ but I don't know how to use that .

Kindly Tell how should I do C and D.

Answer:

> A,B,C,D

Comment: In (d), you have a bounded entire function, hence constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- The product of two differentiable function is differentiable, compose with the diagonal.
- Use the [Liouville theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))